# How to pass parameter to an ActionFilter in WebAPI with Unity DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an actionfilter that I use to decorate my WebApi Actions

```
        [ApiFilter(Api="Online")]
```

Inside my Actionfilter, I have a dependency to my repository class, which I am injecting via Unity

```
public class ApiFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public IOdsRepository _odsRepository { get; set; }

    public string Api { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

       string apiKey=actionContext.Request.GetApiKey();
       if (Api=="...")//problem is this is always null with the Unity resolver for ApiFilterAttribute
     }
```

I feel sure that I just need to tweak how Unity is resolving this, but I'm not sure how to get both the IOdsRepository and Api values.

This is the Unity configuration code, the last line of which is how it is resolving the repository object. How can I change this to also cause the ApiFilter parameters to be passed correctly?

```
  public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
    /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
        // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
        var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add((ApiFilterAttribute)resolver.GetService(typeof(ApiFilterAttribute)));

    }
}
```